# Getting null value on the querySelector

Tags: javascript

I try to copy paste the code from Mozilla's getting started with Javascript tutorial

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

myImage.onclick = function() {
    var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    if(mySrc === 'images/firefox-icon.png') {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/firefox2.png');
    } else {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/firefox-icon.png');
    }
}
```

I am getting an error "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null". How can correct the code?

I am just getting started with javascript. please forgive me if it is a silly mistake from my part.

Comment: Is there an img tag in your page?

Comment: Are you doing this after loading page ?

Comment: As per mdn page you don't have an image "Returns null if no matches are found; otherwise, it returns the first matching element." Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Can you post your html ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to assign the click handler before the element has been rendered so the query selector will not find the img tag. Try executing your script after the page has rendered like so

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

    myImage.onclick = function() {
        var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
        if(mySrc === 'images/firefox-icon.png') {
          myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/firefox2.png');
        } else {
          myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/firefox-icon.png');
        }
    }
}
```